# Criar um valor (value) dinâmico em checkbox usando ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Eu tenho um código ajax http://jsfiddle.net/rubensoul/dcb14q79/ e preciso que os valores que apareçam seja dinâmicos, exemplo:

No link que coloquei tem 3 inputs e no js eu criei para apenas 1, se eu colocasse para todos ele enviaria normalmente

```
    checkbox:$($("#checkbox input")[0]).prop("checked")?$($("#checkbox input")[0]).val():'',
```

Só que eu preciso que esses valores sejam dinâmicos, ou seja, que não precise colocar 1 por 1. eu colocaria somente 1. que ele atribuiria o valor de cada input automáticamente sem precisar mexer novamente nesse código.

É possível e como posso resolver isso?

Fico no aguardo

Comment: Como queres receber isso no PHP? uma string? um JSON?

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de mencionar isso, é por json ele será atualizado ele recebe os valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo teu HTML dá ideia que todos os inputs são descendentes dessa div `#checkbox`.

Assim podes usar o `.find()` para encontrar os inputs e depois usando o `.filter()` e o `.map()` crias uma array com os valores dos que estão checados. Depois podes enviar isso como JSON no AJAX. Usei também o `.get()` do jQuery para me dar uma array nativa e trabalhar só com JavaScript nativo a partir daí.

Algo assim:

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var checkboxes = $(this).find('input[name="checkbox[]"]').get().filter(function (input) {
        return input.checked;
    }).map(function (input) {
        return input.value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "teste4.php",

        data: {
            checkbox: JSON.stringify(checkboxes),
            profissional: $("#profissional").val()
        },
```

Comment: Como ficaria os inputs no html neste caso, ele entrega os valores para o json do teste4? preciso alterar o value="" dele?

Comment: @RubensJunior no HTML é como tens no jsFiddle. O value que passa é respectivamente "clinico", "pediatria" e "dermatologista".

Comment: Deu certo sua dica, resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado

Comment: tudo bem? desculpe voltar a este tópico, mas como faço para neste código voltar ao valor padrão após cancelar o click? ele ta ficando com o mesmo valor de assinalado, fiz algo errado?

Comment: @RubensJunior o que chamas "valor padrão"? o valor que tinha quando abriste a página?

Comment: Ele tem o valor padrão de horário, (que espera o preenchimento de profissional para liberar) e quando clicado em um dos checkbox, ele envia o valor do checkbox, só que ao desmarcar, ele não volta ao 'default' http://rubensoul.com.br/teste/agendar-interno.html

Comment: @RubensJunior conseguiste encontrar o problema? eu não acho que isso esteja relacionado com a minha resposta mas se precisares de ajuda mais logo quando estiver em casa posso dar uma olhada.

Comment: Sua resposta está perfeita, e funcionando. Esse ultima duvida seria somente um complemento